# Printer Brother DCP-110C Linux 64-bit drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, printer

I need 64-bit Linux driver for DCP-110C (for Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit)
I found only 32-bit here.
http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/index.html

I've tried to follow those instructions. During the installation, I got this:

```
ondra@ondra-doma:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg  -i  --force-all dcp110clpr-1.0.2-1.i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
(Reading database ... 257283 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace dcp110clpr 1.0.2-1 (using dcp110clpr-1.0.2-1.i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dcp110clpr ...
Setting up dcp110clpr (1.0.2-1) ...
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/libbrcompij2.so.1.0': File exists
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/libbrcompij2.so.1': File exists
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/libbrcompij2.so': File exists
```

After installation, the printer is listed at the cups server, but does not work (no command has any effect on printer (which is, of course, on and connected)).

Anyone has found some working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found that installing brother drivers from Ubuntu did the work. Not sure if it was conditioned by passing the instructions from the Brother's site first.